# Game logic dynamically extendable architecture implementation patterns

Tags: c#, design-patterns, mvvm

When coding games there are a lot of cases when you need to inject your logic into existing class dynamically and without making unnecessary dependencies.

For an example I have a Rabbit which can be affected by freeze ability so it can't jump.
It could be implemented like this:

```
class Rabbit
{
    public bool CanJump { get; set; }

    void Jump()
    {
        if (!CanJump) return;
        ...
    }
}
```

But If I have more than one ability that can prevent it from jumping? I can't just set one property because some circumstances can be activated simultanously.

Another solution?

```
class Rabbit
{
    public bool Frozen { get; set; }
    public bool InWater { get; set; }
    bool CanJump { get { return !Frozen && !InWater; } }
}
```

Bad. The Rabbit class can't know all the circumstances it can run into. Who knows what else will game designer want to add: may be an ability that changes gravity on an area?

May be make a stack of bool values for CanJump property? No, because abilities can be deactivated not in that order in which they were activated.

I need a way to seperate ability logic that prevent the Rabbit from jumping from the Rabbit itself.

One possible solution for this is making special checking event:

```
class Rabbit
{
    class CheckJumpEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public bool Veto { get; set; }
    }

    public event EventHandler<CheckJumpEvent> OnCheckJump;

    void Jump()
    {
        var args = new CheckJumpEventArgs();
        if (OnCheckJump != null) OnCheckJump(this, args);
        if (!args.Veto) return;
        ...
    }
}
```

But it's a lot of code! A real Rabbit class would have a lot of properties like this (health and speed attributes, etc).

I'm thinking of borrowing something from MVVM pattern where you have all the properties and methods of an object implemented in a way where they can be easily extended from outside. Then I want to use it like this:

```
class FreezeAbility
{
   void ActivateAbility() 
   {
       _rabbit.CanJump.Push(ReturnFalse);
   }

   void DeactivateAbility() 
   {
       _rabbit.CanJump.Remove(ReturnFalse);
   }

   // should be implemented as instance member
   // so it can be "unsubscribed"
   bool ReturnFalse(bool previousValue)
   {
       return false;
   }
}
```

Is this approach good? What also should I consider? What are other suitable options and patterns? Any ready to use solutions?

---

**UPDATE**

The question is not about how to add different behaviors to an object dynamically but how its (or its behavior) implementation can be extended with external logic. I don't need to add a different behavior but I need a way to modify an exitsing one and I also need a possibiliity to undo changes.

Comment: If are you talking about [*Behavior*](http://www.jayway.com/2013/03/20/behaviors-in-wpf-introduction/), then yes, it surely make sense. You could create many *object-specific* behaviors and use them.

Comment: @Sinatr I read that article and I'm not sure I really understand how is it applicable in my case. Is it about that I can make IBehavior with CanJump property, add behaviors list to the Rabbit and walk through the list acquiring each behavior for it's CanJump value? Internally event approach works the same (it maintains subscribers list and invokes them when raised to get the resulting value).

Comment: @Sinatr The article seems to be more about settings representation than how behaviors can be implemented. I don't see how they can affect a value of any property of the object they attached to (except that I said in my previous comment).

Comment: I mean mechanic, not necessary wpf implementation, link is just to show similarity: you have to store instance of the object and provide methods to manipulate it. Then attaching such behavior to any *supported object* will allow you to manipulate *object behavior*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** 
Sorry about misreading the question. My new understanding of the goals.

We have an animal with a behaviour (say Jump) that we wish to modify based upon either the state of the animal (say, Frozen) or the state of the environment (say, the Gravity or the Temperature),

We do not want to keep extending the animal but would like to be able to configure it.

I have a partial solution to extending the functionality. Perhaps it will be sufficient or can be used as a starting point.

We need two new concepts

**IEnvironment** 
Not totally needed, you mention the change in gravity almost as an aside, but simple enough to include

**IStateful / IState** 
We need some criteria against which to test. Instead of adding to the interface we can define the animal as including a bag of states to which we can add or remove.

```
public interface IEnvironment {
    double Gravity { get; set; }
}   

public interface IState {
    string Name { get; }
    bool Is(object target);
}

public interface IStateful {
    void SetState(string  name);
    void SetState(string name, Func<object, bool> test);
    void ClearState(string name);
    bool IsInState(string name);
}
```

We still have the (mostly) same *WithBehaviours* classes, we just add states and externalise the configuration

```
public abstract class WithBehaviors : IStateful {

    private readonly List<IState> _states;
    private readonly List<Behavior> _behaviors;
    private readonly IEnvironment _environment;

    protected WithBehaviors(IEnvironment environment) {
        _environment = environment;
        _behaviors = new List<Behavior>();
        _states = new List<IState>();
    }

    #region IStateful


    public void SetState(string name) {
        SetState(name , o=> true);
    }

    public void SetState(string name, Func<object, bool> test) {
        if (_states.Any(s => Match(s, name))) {
        throw new ArgumentException();
        }
        _states.Add(new State(name, test));
    }

    public void ClearState(string name) {
        _states.RemoveAll(s => Match(s, name));
    }

    public bool IsInState(string name) {
        var theState = _states.FirstOrDefault(s => Match(s, name));
        return theState != null && theState.Is(this);
    }

    private static bool Match(IState state, string name) {
        return state.Name.Equals(name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    }

    #endregion

    public void RegisterBehaviour(string name, Action<object> defaultAction) {
        _behaviors.Add(new Behavior(name, defaultAction));
    }

    public void RegisterBehaviorModifier(
        string name, 
        Func<IEnvironment, IStateful, bool> check,
        Action<object> replacementAction = null
    ) {
        ActOn(name, 
            b => b.BehaviorActions.Add(new BehaviorAction(check, 
                                                          replacementAction ?? (o =>{}))));
    }


    public void Invoke(string behaviourName) {
        ActOn(behaviourName, behavior => {
            var replacement = behavior.BehaviorActions.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Check(_environment, this));
            if (replacement == null) {
                behavior.DefaultAction(this);
            } else {
                replacement.Action(this);
            }
        });
    }

    private void ActOn(string name, Action<Behavior> action) {
        var behavior = _behaviors.FirstOrDefault(b => name.Equals(b.Name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
        if (behavior != null) {
            action(behavior);
        }
    }

    private class Behavior {
        public Behavior(string name, Action<object> defaultAction) {
            Name = name;
            DefaultAction = defaultAction;
            BehaviorActions = new   List<BehaviorAction>();
        }

        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public Action<object> DefaultAction { get; private set; }
        public List<BehaviorAction> BehaviorActions { get; private set; }
    }

    private class BehaviorAction {

        public BehaviorAction(Func<IEnvironment, IStateful, bool> check, Action<object> action) {
            Check = check;
            Action = action;
        }

        public Func<IEnvironment, IStateful, bool> Check { get; private set; }
        public Action<object> Action { get; private set; }

    }

}

public class WithBehaviors<T> : WithBehaviors where T : class {

    public WithBehaviors(IEnvironment environment) : base(environment) {}

    public void RegisterBehaviour(string name, Action<T> defaultAction) {
        base.RegisterBehaviour(name, obj => defaultAction((T)obj));
    }

    public void RegisterBehaviorModifier(
        string name,
        Func<IEnvironment, IStateful, bool> check,
        Action<T> replacementAction = null
    ) {
        base.RegisterBehaviorModifier(name, 
                                      check,
                                      (replacementAction != null)
                                          ? (Action<object>)(o => replacementAction((T)o))
                                          : null);
    }

}


public  class Rabbit : WithBehaviors<Rabbit> {
    public Rabbit(IEnvironment environment) : base(environment){}

    public int XVal { get; set; }

}

public class State : IState {

    private readonly Func<object, bool> _test;

    public State(string name, Func<object, bool> test = null) {
        Name = name;
        _test = test;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public bool Is(object target) {
        return _test(target);
    }
}
```

The State includes a test on the target as well as a simple yes/no, e.g. a Tired state could be defined as Energy below a certain level. May be over-engineering.

```
[TestClass]
public class BehaviorsFixture {

    #region Setup

    private Mock<IEnvironment> _mockEnvironment;

    private Rabbit CreateRabbit() {

        var buggs = new Rabbit(_mockEnvironment.Object);
        buggs.RegisterBehaviour(Behaviors.Jump, r => r.XVal += 10);

        // gravity GTE 30, cannot jump
        buggs.RegisterBehaviorModifier(Behaviors.Jump, (e, o) => e.Gravity >= 30);

        // gravity GTE 20, (but LT 30), jumps 5
        buggs.RegisterBehaviorModifier(Behaviors.Jump, (e, o) => e.Gravity >= 20, r => r.XVal += 5);

        // if the rabbit is frozen it cannot jump
        buggs.RegisterBehaviorModifier(Behaviors.Jump, (e, o) => o.IsInState(States.Frozen));

        // if the rabbit is chilled it can only jump 2
        buggs.RegisterBehaviorModifier(Behaviors.Jump, (e, o) => o.IsInState(States.Chilled), r => r.XVal += 2);

        return buggs;
    }

    #endregion

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialize() {
    _mockEnvironment = new Mock<IEnvironment>();
    _mockEnvironment.SetupProperty(mk => mk.Gravity, 9.81);
    }


    [TestMethod]
    public void JumpingInGravity() {

        var buggs = CreateRabbit();

        Assert.AreEqual(0, buggs.XVal);

        buggs.Invoke(Behaviors.Jump);
        buggs.Invoke(Behaviors.Jump);

        Assert.AreEqual(20, buggs.XVal);

        // higher gravity means can only jump 5
        _mockEnvironment.Object.Gravity = 20.0;

        buggs.Invoke(Behaviors.Jump);

        Assert.AreEqual(25, buggs.XVal);


        // even higher gravity, cannot jump
        _mockEnvironment.Object.Gravity = 30.0;

        buggs.Invoke(Behaviors.Jump);

        Assert.AreEqual(25, buggs.XVal);


        // set gravity back to normal - can jump
        _mockEnvironment.Object.Gravity = 9.81;

        buggs.Invoke(Behaviors.Jump);

        Assert.AreEqual(35, buggs.XVal);

    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void JumpingWhenCold() {

        var buggs = CreateRabbit();

        Assert.AreEqual(0, buggs.XVal);

        buggs.Invoke(Behaviors.Jump);

        Assert.AreEqual(10, buggs.XVal);

        // if frozen, cannot jump
        buggs.SetState(States.Frozen);

        buggs.Invoke(Behaviors.Jump);

        Assert.AreEqual(10, buggs.XVal);

        // remove, can jump again
        buggs.ClearState(States.Frozen);

        buggs.Invoke(Behaviors.Jump);

        Assert.AreEqual(20, buggs.XVal);

        // if chilled, can jump a bit
        buggs.SetState(States.Chilled);

        buggs.Invoke(Behaviors.Jump);

        Assert.AreEqual(22, buggs.XVal);

        // remove, can jump again
        buggs.ClearState(States.Chilled);

        buggs.Invoke(Behaviors.Jump);

        Assert.AreEqual(32, buggs.XVal);

        }
    }

}
```

The outstanding problems are to do with

- Priority of checks - At the moment, the first one we trigger is the one we use. Careful ordering of the config can give the right answer but is error prone. Perhaps add a priority and sort by same when checking
- Modification of existing functionality - At the moment we can replace it  but say gravity allowed us to jump only half normal, there is no way of allowing for this (except again by careful configuration )

I hope this is closer to what you were seeking. Sorry again about the mess-up.

Comment: Your answer is about making behaviors dynamic (can be registered at runtime instead of static interfaces). It's not what I'm asking. You mentioned "one could register the check as a func that checked against the rabbit state before allowing" - this is exactly the subject. But I need to extend not only "IsEnabled" property but also JumpHeight, JumpSpeed, CrouchVisibilityFactor and other properties. The question is about such extension mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a case for a Specification pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern)

Basically you'd probably implement a CanJumpSpecification, which can be satisfied by a rabbit.

This way, the business logic deciding whether your rabbit can jump is encapsulated in its specification, thus removing this from the rabbit.

Specifications are also highly re-usable in polymorphic cases. Say you have not only a rabbit, but also a duck, they're probably both affected by the same rules when it comes to jumping.

You can further chain specifications into more complex specifications by implementing composite specification (also described in the wikipedia article).

Comment: But it's not applicable for numeric values, only for booleans?

Comment: Also it seems to be a problem when you need to undo one of specification instances because it can be wrapped by not known another one.

Comment: If you need to return other data than booleans, I'd rather have a look at the Strategy Pattern. Specifications encapsulate boolean logic.

Answer (score 0):

Obvious way

```
public interface ICanJump
{
    public void Jump();
}
public Rabbit: Animal, ICanJump
{
    public void Jump() { ... }
}

Animal animal = new Rabbit();
if(animal is ICanJump)
    animal.Jump();
```

Behavior

```
abstract class Animal
{
    abstract int Y { get; set; }
}
public class JumpingAnimal
{
    Animal _instance;
    public JumpingAnimal(Animal animal) { _instance = animal; }

    public void Jump()
    {
        _instance.Y += 10;
    }
}

Animal animal = new Rabbit();
var jump = new JumpingAnimal(animal);
jump.Jump();
```

The point is you can store behaviors separately from animals (they don't have to implement it, but there should be something available in abstract/base class to *make this happens*).

Clear?

Comment: Ok, you splitted it in two classes - animal itself and jumping behavior. If I have an ability that affects jumping its behavior should inherit JumpingAnimal and override Jump with empty implementation. Than it should be assigned instead original. How will you undo one of such behaviors (may be not the last)?

Comment: That's the point, you **do not** override anything. Behavior knows something about the object, which is enough to perform that *behave*. Object knows **nothing** about his possible behaviors.

Comment: And you seems to understood it a bit wrong from the first point: both examples shown are implementing `Jump()`. Via interface and via behavior. See the difference. `Y` in second example added to simply show some property for `Jump()` to change.

Comment: From your comment to @AlanT answer. If you put `JumpHeight`, `JumpSpeed`, `CrouchVisibilityFactor`, etc. into `JumpBehavior`, then you get what you need: `Animal` doesn't need to implement, nor to have them. You simply attach behavior (store it in some sort of `Animal` manager as extra data or provide `object[] Behaviour` property in `Animal` specifically to store *future* animal behaviors).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to call for the decorator pattern, where you can either override, or enhance the behavior of a class by decorating with a class of the same type, and repeat as needed. The outer Rabbit class controls the ultimate behavior, so the consuming class does not have wonder what it does, it just calls the method. The ShedThisBehavior() method, returns a Rabbit with the outermost behavior removed.

```
public class Rabbit
{
    protected Rabbit _innerRabbit;
    public virtual void Jump()
    {
        //do something jumpy
    }
    public Rabbit ShedThisBehavior()//aka Get My Inner Rabbit
    {
        if (_innerRabbit == null)
        {
            //this will only happen when the most inner rabbit is reached
            return this; 
        }
        return _innerRabbit;
    }
}

//override the base behavior and don't jump because the rabbit is frozen
public class FrozenRabbit:Rabbit
{

    public FrozenRabbit(Rabbit innerRabbit)
    {
        _innerRabbit = innerRabbit;
    }

    public override void Jump()
    {
        //don't jump
    }
}

//override the base behavior and don't jump because the rabbit is wet
public class WetRabbit : Rabbit
{

    public WetRabbit(Rabbit innerRabbit)
    {
        _innerRabbit = innerRabbit;
    }

    public override void Jump()
    {
        //don't jump
    }
}

//ignore the inner rabit, and jump twice
public class VeryJumpyRabbit : Rabbit
{

    public VeryJumpyRabbit(Rabbit innerRabbit)
    {
        _innerRabbit = innerRabbit;
    }

    public override void Jump()
    {
        base.Jump();
        base.Jump();
    }
}

//do whatever the inner rabbit does for jumping
public class OtherAttributeRabbit : Rabbit
{

    public OtherAttributeRabbit(Rabbit innerRabbit)
    {
        _innerRabbit = innerRabbit;
    }

    public override void Jump()
    {
        _innerRabbit.Jump();
    }
}
```

Comment: What if somebody already have a reference to a rabbit? I was thinking about using Decorator but it doesn't seem to be a solution. I need to affect rabbit properties **dynamically** at runtime. Of course I could make an intermediate proxy-object which will keep an up to date reference to the decorated rabbit but it seems to be too overcomplicated.

Comment: May be State would be more suitable here and if I decorate it... But still I can't undo applied changes because some other changes may be on top of this.

Comment: You couple it with a Factory that takes a Rabbit reference and returns a Rabbit decorated with the newly desired ability.  Not at all complicated.  You're only dealing with one reference since it is always the same type.

Comment: Sorry, in my previous comment I meant Strategy, not State.

Comment: Strategy? Doesn't seem applicable -- you still get into your original trap of deciding which implementation to use depending on the state of the Rabbit. Decorator keeps you from modifying existing code to change behaviors.  Throw in a Factory to add/remove the appropriate decoration and I think you're there.

Comment: I mentioned that Strategy can be wrapped with Decorators and reassigned from outside. About Factory. Let's decorate the rabbit with FrozenRabbit and than StuckedRabbit. Now I want to remove FrozenRabbit effect. To do this Factory should reapply StuckedRabbit on the original Rabbit reference. I see two cons: 1) When I add a new ability effect I should also register its construction in the Factory. Or there should be a "SwapInstance" method on decorators. 2) The first existing FrozenRabbit effect instance will be lost in my example. What if its implementation cantains private members?

Comment: You can always strip down to the original Rabbit by iterating through ShedThisBehavior(), then reapplying a new behavior.I'd write some tests that cover the use cases you'll have, write some code to see if it will meet them.  Then you can see if it is "too complicated" in the actual implementation.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a [Chain of Responsibility](http://www.oodesign.com/chain-of-responsibility-pattern.html) pattern, where the Rabbit class is extended by FrozenRabbit and HeavyRabbit handlers that modify the jump distance (or any other factor of the Rabbit that is affected by the factor the handler is responsible for).

that way you can add more handlers as the game gets more complex, while keeping the Rabbit class clean.

you will need to make sure you use the correct handlers in the correct order according to the state of the environment or rabbit.